# When i am trying to run the code then an error message is occur

Tags: java, selenium

When i am trying to run below mention code the an error message is occur. In my code i am trying to execute logout function. for this logout function, i have prepared a excel where logout xpath properly store. but when i am trying to execute this code an error message is occur.error message is Element is not clickable at point (1155, 20). Other element would receive the click

```
package com.rmspl.multiplemethod;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class MethodSet {
static WebElement element;

public void login (String username,String password,String nr,WebDriver fd) {

     fd.get("http://117.247.65.9/vms_test");
     fd.manage().window().maximize();

    WebElement E1 = fd.findElement(By.name("j_username"));
    E1.sendKeys(username);

    WebElement E2 = fd.findElement(By.name("j_password"));
    E2.sendKeys(password);

    WebElement E3 = fd.findElement(By.name("log"));
    E3.click();

    }

        public void clickLink(String xPath,String nr,String nr1,WebDriver fd){
        element = fd.findElement(By.xpath(xPath));
        element.click();
        }
        public void Select(String xPath,String val,String nr1,WebDriver fd){
        Select sel = new Select(fd.findElement(By.xpath(xPath)));
        sel.selectByValue(val);
  }
}

package com.rmspl.multiplemethod;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class TestDriver {

    static WebElement element;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws BiffException, IOException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, 
    IllegalAccessException,IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {

    MethodSet mt = new MethodSet();

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Arijit Mohanty\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver fd = new ChromeDriver();

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Arijit Mohanty\\Desktop\\Bangla\\HybridDatasheet.xls");
    Workbook WB = Workbook.getWorkbook(fis);
    Sheet Sh = WB.getSheet("Sheet2");

    int rows = Sh.getRows();
    int cols = Sh.getColumns();

    for (int i = 1; i<rows; i++)
        {
        String methodname = Sh.getCell(0, i).getContents();
        String data1 = Sh.getCell(1, i).getContents();
        String data2 = Sh.getCell(2, i).getContents();
        String data3 = Sh.getCell(3, i).getContents();

        Method m1 =  mt.getClass().getMethod(methodname, String.class,String.class,String.class, WebDriver.class);
        m1.invoke(mt,data1,data2,data3,fd);
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: In your code, which line throws this message? can we have the URL of the site?

Comment: When i am trying to click in logout function then error message is occur. Logout function xpath written in excel sheet.Site url-117.247.65.9/vms_test.  username-msrtc, password-Admin. Sharing the Excel data- Methodname-ClickLink, Data1-//a[contains(text(),'Logout')], Data2-Not Required, Data3-Not Required.

Comment: it looks the xpath of the logout button might be correct but there is some other element(something like a notification/popup) is overlaying that logout button. Can help you better if you give the URL

Comment: @Santosh Kumar, i have shared the url. it is right after logging a web popup is appear.. please give your valuable suggestion.

Comment: can you give us username and password. I will login and check logout

Comment: @Santosh kumar here is the credential username-msrtc, password-Admin.

Comment: In chrome, once i have logged in, i am getting password save pop up that hides the logout button. Is this causing issue?

Comment: @Santosh Kumar, thanks for your reply. maybe popup is causing the issue. but when i am execute simple test script on Logging and Logout function then no error message is occur. But whenever i am trying to execute the same test case in data driven testing then an error message is occur.

Comment: can you try using explicit wait until the logout is visible and check?

Comment: @Santosh Kumar,Please guide me where implement explicit wait in my code. i am newer in selenium so please help me.

Comment: In the data driven, before clicking on the logout button, add an explicit wait for the logout button to be visible before trying to click on that?

Comment: Else you can also avoid that popup by initializing chromedriver with certain preference.  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--disable-web-security");
options.addArguments("--no-proxy-server");

Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);

options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs); webDriver driver = new chromeDriver(options);

Comment: @Santosh Kumar, Thank you so much for remarkable help. i'll try your code and give you the feedback.Thanks again..

Comment: @Santosh Kumar,Thanks for your help. After initializing chromedriver preference and execute the code then no popup has been shown. but whenever trying to click into logout link then error message is occur. Given below the  error message....                                                                            
unknown error: Element <a style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:underline; margin-right:10px;" href="/vms_test/logout.jsp">...</a> is not clickable at point (1155, 20). Other element would receive the click: <div id="loading_bg" style="display: block;"></div>

Comment: can you give the xpath/locator that you have used for logout?

Comment: Here is the xpath of logout link. By.xpath(//a[contains(text(),'Logout')])

Comment: Site is down now. will check once its up @Arijit

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for loading_bg till goes off the screen. please update the method clickLink as given below. please try and let us know.

```
public void clickLink(String xPath,String nr,String nr1,WebDriver fd){
   new WebDriverWait(fd, 90).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("loading_bg")));
   element = fd.findElement(By.xpath(xPath));
   element.click();
```

}

Comment: @Thanks Murti.. your code working properly. Thank you so much.Thanks a lot. asked you one things what is the loading_bg. this loading _bg is shown in error message. If possible then please reply.

Comment: It is a id for the loading background which is used to block the UI until some back ground process to complete. You need to wait for that. Some application, it will be loading bar / symbol. I don't know about your app.

Comment: Thanks @Murthi for your outstanding explanation and your help. it means a lot. thanks once again.Now this code working properly.